# how to see logs in 'Run window' on Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

before i updated android studio to recently version,

i could see logs in Run window, and that was good to see than logcat because log was more simplified and easy to see.

but after i updated my android studio, there is only messages like this.

==========================================================

2023-09-18 11:21:29: Launching app on '.
$ adb shell am start -n "" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER

Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp= }

Open logcat panel for (5200cf9346c9458b)
Connected to process 4785 on device ''.

==========================================================

can i make it appear on Run window as it before??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how to return it to what it used to be *precisely*, but **the next best thing** I use is the following:

1. Click here:

[image]

2. Select the logcat to open automatically:

[image]

3. Enjoy browsing your logs while testing the app!